# How do I upload Image using Bootstrap Card and Django for loop?

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I am trying to upload image. I used Django for loop and inside it placed Bootstrap Card.

1. I have added the code of models.py and views.py:
2. The problem I am facing is that the images are not appearing on the browser while rest of the details such as name and price is loading perfecting.

**Products**

```
{% for product in products   %}

  <div class="row">
     <div class="column">
       <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="{{product.image_url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{product.name}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">${{product.price}}</p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">ORDER NOW</a>
          </div>
       </div>
     </div>
  </div>
   <ul>

{% endfor %}
```

`enter code here:
models.py

```
 from django.db import models


 class zoho(models.Model):
 name= models.CharField(max_length=255)
 price=models.FloatField()
 stock=models.IntegerField()
 imageurl=models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

`

```
enter code here 
views.py

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import zoho


def index(request):
    products= zoho.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'products': products})
```

Comment: can you show your models.py

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for product in products %}
    .....     
    <img src="{{product.image.url}}" alt="Product Image" class="img-fluid">
    .......
    ......
{% endfor %}


<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form | crispy}}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm mr-3 mb-2 px-3 py-1" value="Save" />
    .....
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

image_url = models.ImageField(upload_to ='upload_profile_to')`enter code here`

Comment: Put the code inside code bracket. Add a brief explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In your models.py, you're saving the image link to *imageurl* and not *image.url* as you're currently calling it in the for loop block.
So, correct the way you called the variable in the for loop block

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).